# In SwiftUI, how can I put the navigation bar in the inner view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI I want to implement the following view. But I have no idea how I can put the navigation bar in the white view inside. Because it is placed on top of the purple view by default.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
        Color.purple
            WhiteView() // the white view
                .padding(.top, 30)
                .padding()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct WhiteView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.white
        .cornerRadius (12)
    }
}

struct WhiteView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WhiteView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach - use NavigationView over color view, so it takes frame of parent view but not full screen

Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

```
struct WhiteView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.white
        .overlay(NavigationView {
                NavigationLink("Test", destination: Text("Details"))
            })
        .cornerRadius (12)
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

I took your code, stuck it in a `NavigationView`, added a `.navigationTitle`, `.toolbar` and `ToolBarItem` and this is the View I got:
[image]

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.purple
                WhiteView() // the white view
                    .padding(.top, 30)
                    .padding()
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .navigationTitle("Your Friends")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Text("Right Button")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct WhiteView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.white
            .cornerRadius (12)
        
    }
}
```

What, exactly is your question/problem? Everything is in the white area.